# atk4 grid lookup dropdown values

Tags: php, orm, atk4

i've got a last question, is it possible to make a grid value lookup, examples:

db values =1 -> label = label1 (dropdown values), how i can define table element to make 
automatic lookup?

```
 $this->addField('tipo_mat');
```

Array lookup -> array(1->'Label1',2->'Label2');

thank's

Comment: What is that **I've last question?**

Comment: what do you mean by "grid lookup value" ?

Comment: I mean that my dropdown array have a key and a label, but in my database i save the key value of array non label, in my grid i want to display the relative label (key -> show label in grid). So when i define grid field tipo_mat, how i can define it like array key/values? thank's a lot

Answer (score 3, accepted):

i've solution

```
    $this->addField('tipo_mat')->calculated(true);

    function calculate_tipo_mat(){
            return " CASE WHEN tipo_mat=1 THEN 'Granito' ELSE 'Marmo' END";


    }
```

thank's everybody